# ModuleNotFoundError after installing with Pip

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module

(Using VSCode)
I'm at a relatively beginner level in python, and I've been attempting to create a telegram bot which  requires the following modules:
datetime, pytz, telegram, and telegram.ext

Here's the import code:

```
from datetime import *
from telegram.ext import *
from telegram import *
from pytz import *
```

For some reason, telegram.ext, telegram and pytz all don't seem to be installed, and I keep getting the error message "ModuleNotFound".

I've went ahead and tried to pip install each module with the following code:

```
pip install python-telegram-bot
```

(from what I understand only one of the two telegram modules should be installed)

```
pip install pytz
```

These should result in both of them being imported, but it once again returns `"ModuleNotFound"` when debugging.

I have also changed my interpreter to `Desktop\MyProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe`, and after completely checking all installs once more, I am once again met with `ModuleNotFound`.

Comment: Have you tried restarting VS Code? Was your virtual environment active when you did pip install?

Comment: How, exactly, did you install those modules?

Comment: @Fractalism I have restarted VS Code, I believe that my virtual environment was active...although I don't completely understand what that means.

Comment: @JohnGordon I installed them in the terminal with pip install [module name]

Comment: Show us the output of this terminal command `pip --version` and also this python code `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: @JohnGordon here is the pip --version:

pip 22.3.1 from C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.11)

Comment: @JohnGordon Here is what I got from the import:
3.11.0 (main, Oct 24 2022, 18:26:48) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: Okay, one more: `print(sys.executable)`

Comment: @JohnGordon C:\Python311\python.exe

Comment: @MZ May you elaborate on the venv not being the correct one?

Comment: @TKS disregard my last comments. If you are getting `C:\Python311\*` in both your `sys` path as well as `pip`, you haven't activated your virtual environment at all in the command line. Your issue is somewhere else. You can also see what packages you have installed with `pip freeze` or `pip list`.

Comment: @MZ I used pip list just now, and I saw that telegram, pytz, pip and python-telegram-bot are all there.

Comment: @MZ What do you think could be the next step?

Comment: Maybe change the interpreter (in vscode) to `C:\Python311\python.exe`. Unless you still want to use a virtual environment.

Comment: @Fractalism sorry for the late reply: I already have the interpreter set to python.exe. This has achieved no results

Answer (score 0):

This is because there are multiple python interpreters in your environment and the wrong one is selected.

You can use shortcuts **"Ctrl+Shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** to choose the correct interpreter.

Another way is to install the package in the current interpreter.
For example, if you are using conda environment, you may use command `conda install packageName`.

Comment: What is the correct interpreter? Is it specific to a device? Or is it the same on each one?

Comment: It's the interpreter where you installed your packages. Different interpreters mean different environment, In A environment you cannot find the packages which you installed in B environment.